# How to update BIOS if update is not available for installed OS?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, bios

I can't update BIOS. The problem is that the BIOS update is not available for the Windows 8, it's available only for Windows 7. I can't install Windows 7 because I can't access BIOS. To access the BIOS I have to first update it. So please tell me how do I update the BIOS?

Comment: You should at least mention what motherboard/bios do you have. Also link to vendor's site where you found update package for Windows 7 would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

BIOS updates are OS-agnostic. It's manufacturer's mistake that it's labeled as Windows 7 version. You can just download and run it on Windows 8.

However, if you can't access BIOS, then updating it is unlikely to fix this issue. Maybe you have UEFI with Quick Boot enabled? Try these steps:

> 1. Press the <kbd>Windows key</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>, or swipe in from the right edge of the screen to open your Charms.
> 2. Click Settings.
> 3. Click Change PC Settings.
> 4. In PC Settings, select General.
> 5. Under Advanced startup, click Restart now. The system will restart and show the Windows 8 boot menu.
> 6. In the boot menu, select Troubleshoot.
> 7. In the Troubleshoot menu, select Advanced options.
> 8. In the Advanced options menu, select UEFI Firmware Settings.
> 9. Click Restart to restart the system and enter UEFI (BIOS).
>
> <sub>Source: [this post by Ramhound](https://superuser.com/a/701633/194694)</sub>

Comment: In the Advanced options menu i get the options like System restore,command prompt,system image recovery,startup setting and startup repair ...which i select ?

Comment: *Startup settings*, I think.

Comment: @ALISHEKH Any progress on this issue?